# Why is the Hessian $\nabla^2 f$ for a smooth function $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, for a smooth manifold $M$, a $(0,2)$-tensor field?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(\frak M,g)$ be a semi-riemannian manifold, with unique levi-civita connection $\nabla$.Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\frak M)$, and let´s define the hessian as the map $\nabla^2 f: \frak{X}(M)  \times \frak{X}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined explicitly by the mapping $(X,Y) \mapsto \nabla^2_{X,Y}f := X(Y(f))-(\nabla_{X}Y)(f)$.

I understand how to show that $\nabla^2f$ is $C^{\infty}$-linear as well as the identities $$\nabla^2_{X,Y}f = \nabla^2_{Y,X}f$$ as well as $$\nabla^2_{X,Y}f = \langle \nabla_{X} \operatorname{grad} f, Y \rangle.$$  But I don´t understand the tensorial property, it seems that we have a map from the cartesian product of vector fields over $\frak{M}$ to smooth functions from $\frak{M}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not clear how the mapping such that $\forall p \in \frak{M}$, we get a tensor $t:\frak{T}_p\frak{M} \times T_p \frak{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined?

Comment: For a given $p$ its a map from product of tangent spaces to $\mathbb{R}$ and its a linear map. Defined by sampling the map at $p$ i.e., take $ <\nabla_{X(p)} \ grad f, Y(p)>$ and define  $t(p)(u,v) = <\nabla_{v} \ grad f, u>$  ? May i know the problem with this definition ?

Comment: Google “tensor characterization lemma” or something along these lines. This issue has been discussed several times (and you can find a detailed proof in Lee’s smooth manifolds book, which is where I first saw this terminology. you can also find it in many other books, eg Spivak vol I). The magic ingredients: bump functions and $C^{\infty}(M)$-linearity

Comment: @peek-a-boo I believe you mean "Tensor field reconstruction theorem"? Lee:s "Smooth Manifolds" does never mention the hessian explicitly. This issue has not been discussed as far as I have been able to see, here. If I am wrong, please give me a link to said thread.

Comment: There’s nothing special about hessian. It takes two vector fields and spits out a scalar field in a $C^{\infty}(M)$-multilinear fashion. Therefore there is a corresponding smooth section of the tensor bundle $T^0_2(TM)$. And I mean the “Tensor characterization lemma”, it is lemma 12.24 of Lee’s introduction to smooth manifolds.

Comment: Yes, TFRT it is an existence theorem, that gives us that there exists a $(0,2)$-tensor such that $\nabla^2 f = \nabla^2f_t$ is a $(0,2)$-tensor field, but I was asking about how the explicit mapping looks. TFRT just says that for each map $$A \in L^{r,s}_{C^{\infty}}$$ there exists a $t \in \mathcal{T}^{r}_{s}(M)$ such that $A = A_t$.

Comment: Well, actually, you might be correct, I believe I can use the proof of TFRT (which by quick glance at your reference seems like a more general case of "Tensor characterization lemma").  Anyways, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Or I should rather say very related, I am not sure it is a generalization.

Comment: There are two things to show. 1) it does not depend on local coordinates. Since your definition does not use coordinates, this follows immediately. 2) the value of the Hessian at a point depends only the tangent vectors $X,Y$ at that point. This can be seen by writing the Hessian with respect to local coordinates and observing that it has no derivatives of the vector fields.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize: the section $H$, of the $(0,2)$ tensor bundle, you’re looking for is defined as follows: for each point $p\in M$ and each pair of tangent vectors $\xi_p,\eta_p\in T_pM$, construct smooth vector fields $X,Y$ on $M$ such that $X(p)=\xi_p$ and $Y(p)=\eta_p$. Then, set
\begin{align}
H_p(\xi_p,\eta_p)&:=[(\nabla^2f)(X,Y)](p)\in\Bbb{R}.
\end{align}
The fact that the definition of $H$ does not depend on the specific choice of extensions $X,Y$, and that $H$ is a smooth section of the tensor bundle $T^0_2(TM)$ is precisely the content of the tensor-characterization lemma.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\nabla^2_{XY}f &= \nabla_X(Yf) - (\nabla_XY)f\\
&= \nabla_{X^i\partial_i}(Y^j\partial_jf) - X^i\nabla_{\partial_i}(Y^j\partial_j)f\\
&= X^iY^j\partial^2_{ij}f + X^i\partial_iY^j\partial_jf - X^i\partial_iY^j\partial_jf - X^iY^j\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_jf\\
&= X^iY^j(\partial^2_{ij}f - \Gamma^k_{ij}\partial_kf).
\end{align*}